# Python database connection

Tags: python

In python is it possible to add connection timeout in the below code,if possible then please help me

```
connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source="+options.server+";Initial Catalog="+options.database+";Integrated Security=SSPI" 
Connection = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Recordset')
Connection.ActiveConnection = connectionString
Connection.ActiveConnection.CommandTimeout = 3600
```

Answer (score 1):

Read a generic example here: http://programming-guides.com/python/timeout-a-function

Comment: Hi,thanks for answer but what I want is  it possible to add ADODB.Recordset  and ADODB.connection together and if it is posible then please give some example

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to actively create (and open) the connection:

```
conn = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
conn.CommandTimeout = 3600
conn.Open(connection_string)
```

And then you can do stuff like:

```
rs = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.RecordSet')
rs.Open(qry, conn)
```

(I guess you can also set the `ActiveConnection` and `CommandText` etc... of the recordset and then execute, but I always thought `Open()` was the easier way, and my knowledge of the api is rusty to say the least...)

Personally, I find it easier to use a module that follows the standard Python [db api](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), such as adodbapi (included with pywin32, which you are already using), which also uses the COM api, but takes care of that "under the hood", or [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/).

Example with adodbapi:

```
conn = adodbapi.connect(conn_string, timeout=3600)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(qry)
```

And a final tip: have a look at [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) which makes things even easier (even if you're not using the other stuff like the ORM)